# Ruby Sequel Equivalent to LINQ to SQL select anonymous objects

Tags: c#, ruby, linq, sequel

I've got some C# code with a LINQ query I'm trying to translate to Ruby and am using Sequel as my DB ORM. The linq query just performs some joins and then returns an anonymous object containing references to the joined entities. I've got the code translated and operating correctly but it just returns all of the columns from each table and I'd like to wrap each set of columns up in its own object similarly to how it is done in the C# code.

LINQ Query

```
from s in slots
join tu in _dbContext.table_usages on s.id equals tu.slot_id
join r in _dbContext.Reservations on tu.reservation_id equals r.ReservationID
join o in _dbContext.orders on r.OrderID equals o.OrderID
join c in _dbContext.Contacts on r.ContactID equals c.ContactID
where tu.reservation_id != null &&
      r.state != ReservationStates.Cancelled
select new { SlotId = s.id, Reservation = r, Order = o, Contact = c, TableUsage = tu };
```

Ruby Code:

```
select(:slots__id, :reservations.*, :orders.*, :restaurant_customers.*, :table_usages.*)
.filter(slots__restaurant_id: restaurant_id, slots__removed: false)
.filter(slots__slot_time: start_time..end_time)
.join(:table_usages, slot_id: :id)
.join(:reservations, id: :table_usages__reservation_id)
.join(:orders, id: :reservations__order_id)
.join(:restaurant_customers, id: :reservations__contact_id)
.filter('table_usages.reservation_id is not null')
.filter('reservations.state != ?', ReservationStates.cancelled)
```

I'm unable to find a way of accomplishing this via the docs but I thought I would see if anyone has done something similar in a way that I haven't thought of yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are just referring to the last two lines:

```
.filter('table_usages.reservation_id is not null')
.filter('reservations.state != ?', ReservationStates.cancelled)
```

Which you could handle via:

```
.exclude(:table_usages__reservation_id=>nil)
.exclude(:reservations__states=>ReservationStates.cancelled)
```

exclude operates as an inverse filter.

Comment: I'm not, I'm more referring to the first line, good call on exclude though. I had changed those to a filter with ~{} to inverse it but that is much nicer, not sure why I didn't think of that